# Prove a language $A_{PTM}$ is not BPP-Complete

Tags: turing-machines, proof-techniques, probability-theory

I am trying to prove that there are a language is not BPP-Complete. There are a couple of examples online, but they are not the best examples and are a bit complicated. I spoke with one of my computer science professors about the problem and he proposed the following proof sketch:

*Proof (sketch):*

We know $A_{TM} \le_m A_{PTM}$.

Construct a decider $D$ that given a Probabilistic Turing Machine $M$ and a string $x$, $D$ accepts if $M$ accepts $x$, and rejects otherwise. As $A_{TM} \le_m A_{PTM}$, a solution to $A_{PTM}$ would yield a solution to $A_{TM}$. However, $A_{TM}$ is not decidable, so therefore, $D$ cannot exist.

*End of Proof*

Where I am confused is how does this show $A_{PTM}$ is not BPP-Complete? As an acceptance problem, I would think $A_{PTM}$ is BPP-Hard, but I don't see how this shows it is not in BPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that a language is not BPP-complete, it suffices to do one of the following:

- Show that the language is not in BPP.
- Show that the language is not BPP-hard.

Your language seems to be undecidable, and so in particular, not in BPP.

Comment: So a BPP-hard language can be undecidable?

Comment: Yes, there is no reason why not. Perhaps you can even find an example.

Comment: Isn't $A_{PTM}$ a BPP-hard language?

Comment: That's a nice question for you to ponder.

Comment: If a language is in BPP then it is decided by a PTM with at least a 2/3 acceptance probability, so any BPP language can be reduced to $A_{PTM}$ because $A_{PTM}$ simply simulates a PTM and outputs accept if it accepts. Am I heading in the right direction here?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it as one rather than in the comments.